# Why does SYSTEMTIME::wDayOfWeek begin with 0 for sunday?

Tags: date, datetime, winapi

Can anyone here tell me why the week begins at 0 for sunday with SYSTEM_TIME::wDayOfWeek ? Here in Germany the week begins at monday. But maybe I'm missing that for other cultures the week begins at sunday.

Comment: "*Can anyone here tell me why ...*" - because that is the way Microsoft designed it. What more do you want to know? You will have to ask Microsoft if you want to know the *reason* why it was designed that way.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I suspect that this design-decision is not made arbitrarily but there are good reasons behind that.

Comment: The precedent was set by `struct tm`, which uses 0 for sunday.

Answer (score 0):

The modern calendar was sponsored by Pope Gregory XIII.  So regardless of one's personal beliefs about religion, it's necessary to look at what the designers of the Gregorian calendar believed:

1. In Genesis, the creation takes six days followed by one day of rest.  It doesn't actually matter whether those were literal days, because the follow-up commandment to rest on each seventh day was talking about a literal day.  That seventh day on which to rest was called "Sabbath" by the Jews.
2. In the gospels, the time of week isn't left to the imagination.  Perfume could not be applied to the body of the Messiah as he was buried (as it was a feast day) or on the next day (as it was a Sabbath), so the women arrived at the tomb **on the morning following the Sabbath**, and recorded that they found it empty and thereafter spoke to a resurrected Messiah.

In honor of these two events in which the designers of and early adherents to the Gregorian calendar deeply believed, they made a weekend out of (a) the Sabbath (our Saturday), which was by definition the seventh day of one week, and (b) the weekday corresponding to resurrection (our Sunday), which therefore had to be the first day of the next week.

And that's why, in the Gregorian calendar, the week starts on Sunday.  This is the system followed in the USA where the majority of OS APIs were designed, including the Windows API.